# Migrate PostgreSQL database back to local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, heroku

I've recently re-installed Mac OS X on my Macbook, and am just getting my development environment and projects back up and running again. For one of my Ruby on Rails apps (which is running on Heroku) I need to grab the (PostgreSQL) database from Heroku and migrate it back to my development environment. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by first creating my database (`psql` in Terminal) and then using the `CREATE DATABASE db_name` command. Then I used `heroku pg:backups capture` to capture a backup/shot of the database. I downloaded this using `heroku pg:backups public-url b001` and then `pg_restore --dbname=db_name --verbose /path/to/download`.

Hope that hopes anyone!